# Accessing private fields from different modules

Tags: rust

```
mod root {
    mod foo {
        pub struct Foo {
            i: i32,
        }
    }
    mod bar {
        pub struct Bar {
            f: ::root::foo::Foo,
        }
        impl Bar {
            pub fn new(i: i32) -> Self {
                Bar { f: ::root::foo::Foo { i: i } }
            }
        }
    }
}
fn main() {}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a3d83152784807978c042c301cbcb610&version=stable&backtrace=0)

The user should be able to interact with `Foo`, but the user should not be able to construct it manually because it is unsafe.

The module `bar` should still be able to construct Foo. As far as I know the only way to do this is to put `Foo` inside the `root` module or inside the `bar` module.

Is there a cleaner way to solve this problem? I named the modules here `foo` and `bar` but in my code they are separate files like `foo.rs` `bar.rs`. Is possible to put `foo.rs` `bar.rs` into the same module so that they can see the private fields but still be live in separate files?

My current workaround was to expose a public unsafe `new` method for Foo.

Comment: Why don't you write a `Foo::new` function that creates a `Foo` safely?

Comment: Could you just set up a getter for the private var you want to access? That way you could guard against any kind of access.

You could also do something like, in the constructor of Foo (so using new), gate the construction such that it will succeed only if a condition of some kind is met, like the required constructor arg must be an instance of a qualifying component, etc. You can't construct the component without being to supply a specific instance of a specific type, and if it's already been constructed, don't create a new one, return the existing one, or some such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a better workaround

```
pub mod root {
    use self::foo::create_foo;
    mod foo {
        pub struct Foo {
            i: i32,
        }
        impl Foo{
            pub fn hello_foo(&self){
                println!("Hello foo");
            }
        }
        pub fn create_foo(i: i32) -> Foo{
            Foo { i: i }
        }
    }
    pub mod bar {
        pub struct Bar {
            pub f: ::root::foo::Foo,
        }
        impl Bar {
            pub fn new(i: i32) -> Self {
                Bar { f: ::root::foo::create_foo(i) }
            }
        }
    }
}
fn main() {
    //still private
    //let f = root::foo::create_foo(42);
    let b = root::bar::Bar::new(42);
    b.f.hello_foo();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=251b6a251b87fbc08df110090e46dfd6&version=stable&backtrace=0)

I expose a public constructor `create_foo` in `foo` but the module `foo` still remains private and I only expose `create_foo` in `root` which means that `bar` can now create a `Foo` but `create_foo` is still private outside of `root`.